# How can handle the local authentication when a SSO website is down?

Tags: authentication, architecture, single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid

We are developing an `SSO` application using `IdentityServer4` as the authentication (not authorization) infrastructure for other (`client`) websites in our company. One of our main concerns is the failure of the SSO website. In this situation, what considerations should we consider to minimize `clients` issues?

For example, we want to create a local login page in each application and ask each application to authenticate it using the `OTP` mechanism. Is this enough or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, you should not try to add some local login, it will just make things more complicated, complex and probably less secure.

Because your tokens have certain lifetime (like 1 hour default and if your SSO goes down for a short while, then you clients can continue to operate (unless you query your SSO all the time).

If you want to make it more reliable, then you need to start looking at load-balancers and having multiple instances running of IdentityServer. That can work if you do take care to have the same keys on all the instances.

Comment: I agree with you @Tore Nestenius, just adding one more point. If you are using a `JWT` token then it will work until it expires but in case you are using a `Reference token` then it will fail to validate the token in WebApi so think from that perspective as well.

Comment: if all the instances share the same database, then the reference tokens will be the same, so it should work with reference tokens as well.

Comment: @ToreNestenius No, I don't query `SSO` constantly, but I use `Reference Tokens` and `Hybrid Flows` for most of our customers. So I better look for `load balancers` or other options

Comment: If you use load-balancers, do be careful about the keys for both the Data Protection API and the signing keys. The data protection key must be the same for all instances and the signing keys also must be the same.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Any useful links or documents will be appreciated

Comment: For Data Protection the documentation is ok, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0 , In my Identity training classes I use Azure Key Vault to store the different keys. Letting your instances use AKV for keys is a good approach.